# Error while editing parent of phabricator task using arc arcanist command line

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

```
 [530]$echo '{ "objectIdentifier":"T1111", "transactions": [ { "type"    "parents.add", "value": ["T2222"] } ] }' 
    | arc call-conduit --conduit-uri  https://phab.somecompany.com/
      --conduit-token cli-xyzlmnop  maniphest.edit
```

The error I'm seeing

```
{"error":"ERR-CONDUIT-CORE","errorMessage":"ERR-CONDUIT-CORE: Edge transactions must have destination PHIDs as in edge lists (found key \"T2222\" on transaction of type \"4\").","response":null}
```

ERR-CONDUIT-CORE: Edge transactions must have destination PHIDs as in edge lists

(trying to follow instructions from [here](https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/maniphest.edit/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The added parent must be specified as a PHID (`PHID-TASK-tpp2tfkdc4vxhae3uxzy`), not a Monogram (`T2222`). You can find the PHID from the Monogram using [`maniphest.search`](https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/maniphest.search/)